# How to @AttributeOverride a Map located in an @Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to implement an `@Embeddable` that contains a `@ElementCollection Map<String, String>`. The implementation is working fine as long as I use this embeddable only once within an `@Entity`. As soon as I need it twice it either fails with an unique constraint error or a duplicate mapping exception. Until now I was not able to identify the correct `@AttributeOverride` declaration, so I could use some help :)

I'm not sure if we are able to override the jointable for an element collection, but I think this should solve the issue.

One solution could be to abandon the Embeddable class for good, but then I would have to create a lot of mapping declarations which I would like to avoid if possible.

Here's the code:

```
@Embeddable
public class MultilingualText {

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "lang")
    @Column(name = "text")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @SortNatural
    public SortedMap<String, String> texts;

    // getters / setters
}

// This one is fine.
@Entity
public class Location  extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Embedded
    private MultilingualText labels;
}

// This one fails 
@Entity
public class Skill extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( "what do do here? ")
    private MultilingualText category;

    @NotNull
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( "what do do here? ")
    private MultilingualText name;
}
```

Comment: As the book PRO JPA 2 notes: 'There is no way to override the collection table for an element collection in an embeddable.'. You can however override Entity relationships defined in an Embeddable by using @AssocationOverride(s) annotations.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is what I feared a little. I moved now from using embeddable to entity and all troubles go away. The big difference is that now all texts are within one single table instead of one per property (which might be desired or not). Quite a limitation.